# Process Explorer System Info CPU red line surge

Tags: cpu, windows-server-2008-r2

[image]

On a Windows 2008 server, I see a regular surge of CPU usage.

Looking at the processes in ProcExp by eye, doesn't highlight anything in particular as the cause.

How can I find out what is causing this increase in CPU activity?

Comment: Hovering the mouse over the graph provides additional information on a tooltip. Red means kernel times.

Comment: Yes. But all is says is CPU x%